# How to browse results with php mssql?

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm working with php and I want to do a next button that's step to the next 10 records (like when you browse question with stackoverflow)
I don't know how to do that but I'm thinking to do it with Top n record ? Do you think that's a good idea ? Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean MS SQL Server, or MySQL?  How you do this is very different between the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for doing it in PHP, you can easily make the button send a POST or GET request for the starting amount.  For instance, a user would make the initial request and that is just `yoursite.com/search.php`, and the next button would send them to the same page with the same search criteria only send an additional field of "start", (i.e. `yoursite.com/search.php?start=10`).  And in the code, you can simply check for it:

```
if(isset($_POST['start'])) {
    //code to add to the search string to start at $_POST['start']
}
```

**Edit 1:**  [This article](http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/how-to-make-limit-from-to-in-mssql-2005.html) is the best I could find as to how to replicate MySQL's `LIMIT` function.  Also, [this one](http://www.posteet.com/view/1567) has a more definitive query to reference, but it's the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

I know in MySQL you can use LIMIT X, Y where X is the lower bound of the return and Y is the upper bound.  So if you wanted to return 10-20 you would use LIMIT 10, 20.  Not sure what the MS-SQL equivalent is.

Answer (score 0):

doesn't mssql have something like LIMIT in mysql? so you could do:

```
select xxx from yyy LIMIT 0,10
```

for first 10 results, then do LIMIT 10,20 for next 10 results etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't. TOP lets you do LIMIT 0,10 but it doesn't let you do LIMIT 10,20.

Comment: ? He is using limit in the answer, not top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's limit

Set a variable called:

```
$limit = 10;
$pl = $_GET["page"] * $limit;
if(!isset($_GET["page"]) || $_GET["page"] == 1)
{
    $pl = 0;
}
```

and in your query do

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT %d,%d" 
mysql_real_escape_string($pl),
mysql_real_escape_string($limit));
```

Btw this is from memory but i think it works.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be any help to you?

```
$count=$_POST[page]*10;
```

Comment: argh, apparently the MSSQL query is causing stackoverflow to not accept the answer.  One sec, I'll get it posted.

Comment: Rather, refer to this since stackoverflow will simply nto accept the query (I have no idea why):
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

for MySQL:

```
$rowsPerPage = 10;
$offset = ((int)$_GET['page'] - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

$result = mysql_query(
    sprintf('select xxx from yyy LIMIT %d,%d', $offset, $rowsPerPage)
);
```