# Store info on mySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm working on a website, where I want to store some user inputs, in a mySQL database.

I've searched all over, but everyone who writes about a simple example, never showns the complete source code.

I'm totally new to PHP and mySQL, so I really need it to be dead simple... :-)

Thank you in advance...

//Kenneth

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is a perfect code sample using the mysql extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will need to call [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-connect.php) to connect to your database which I assume exists. You can use the sample code below:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

Then you will need to select a database using [mysql_select_db()](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-select-db.php):

```
$db = mysql_select_db('db');
```

Now it's time for a mysql_query()! You will need to know the language SQL to do more advanced queries.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ("john", "passwd", "john@example.com")', $link);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
$db= mysql_select_db('yourDBname');
$query="your query here";
mysql_query($query,$conn);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should never use mysql_* it's old and slow.
[PDO](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2004/may/first-steps-with-pdo/) is what you are looking for. It's fast, safe, and easy to use

Comment: Since when is mysql_* slower than PDO?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402017/php-pdo-vs-normal-mysql-connect` 3 post

Comment: This is valid advise. But wrong in its imperative form. PDO is not more secure and faster by itself. Only if you also utilize prepared statements. "Just using PDO" is misleading to newcomers in that regard. And it should really be the ease of use advantages which should be stressed. (Also please avoid msg speak; and if it's a one-liner it should have been [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Anyway +1 because it might be very relevant to OP.)