# How to retrieve from database correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and I am having issues pulling this data in.. It is finding the records according to the debugger but then for some reason the page comes blank. Can anyone please help me with this for loop to retrieve the fields?, i think this is where the issue is. I tried with and without that while loop (which i think is wrong there) and nothing

```
 echo '<table class="table_content">
             <tr>
                 <td class="td_order" colspan="3" width="800px">
              Descriptions                  </td>
           </tr><tr>';

    for($counter = 0; $row2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2); $counter++)
                  {

                   while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                          $_name = $row["_name"];
                          $_image = $row["_image"];
                          $_disc = $row["_disc"];
                      }
                        print("<td valign='top' width='230px' height='300px'>");
                        print("<p style='font-size:18px; color:blue; padding:0;'>$_name</p>");
                        print("<img class='custom' alt='' src='$_image'/>");
                        print("<p>$_disc</p>");
                       print('</td>');
                    }
                  }

           echo '</tr></table> ';
```

I think I am doing something wrong with this logic for the loop, I have tried several things.. but nothing... I would appreciate your help.

PS: The connections works, the query works.. The data being retrieve is as foollow

```
_name        _image                _disc   
Benjamin    images/benjamin.jpg    He's a great person
Jairo       images/jairo.jpg       Jairo has experience as a civil engineer..
```

Comment: Use PDO instead of mysql_* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402017/php-pdo-vs-normal-mysql-connect

Comment: The first bad thing that I see is that using this while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) you'll only get the last data from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the for and while loop and change it with ;

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
   $_name = $row["_name"];
   $_image = $row["_image"];
   $_disc = $row["_disc"];
   ..
```

Comment: but this would give me only one row no?

Comment: No, you'll get the all row one by one .. in your case first row will be; "Benjamin    images/benjamin.jpg    He's a great person"; and then second row will be "Jairo       images/jairo.jpg       Jairo has experience as a civil engineer.."

Comment: Yes this worked thank you, how about if I need to create a <tr> then several <tds> and then close the <tr> then go again for another <tr> and repeat the process?

Comment: put them also in while loop.. while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){
   $_name = $row["_name"];
   $_image = $row["_image"];
   $_disc = $row["_disc"];
   echo "<tr><td>".$_name."</td><td>".$_image."</td></tr>"; /*..*/ }

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding a bit more professional approach to your application and deploying a template system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). You'll benefit from separating your view from the logic, have caching and easily maintainable code.

In the circumstances, you could solve your problem in a following way: [Example 7.33. Database example with {foreachelse}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#id427576):

```
<?php 
  include('Smarty.class.php'); 

  $smarty = new Smarty; 

  $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test'; 
  $login = 'test'; 
  $passwd = 'test'; 

  // setting PDO to use buffered queries in mysql is 
  // important if you plan on using multiple result cursors 
  // in the template. 

  $db = new PDO($dsn, $login, $passwd, array( 
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true)); 

  $res = $db->prepare("select * from users"); 
  $res->execute(); 
  $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_LAZY); 

  // assign to smarty 
  $smarty->assign('res',$res); 

  $smarty->display('index.tpl');?>
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result2 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're fetching the row twice which means you'll not echo half the rows. This solution keeps things a bit cleaner with foreach and some inline echoing of the variables. If PHP short tags are enabled you can use `<?= $foo ?>` in place of `<?php echo $foo ?>`

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
?>
<td valign="top" width="230px" height="300px">
    <p style="font-size:18px; color:blue; padding:0;"><?php echo $row['_name'] ?></p>
    <img class="custom" alt="" src='<?php echo $row['_image'] ?>"/>
    <p><?php echo $row['_disc'] ?></p>
</td>
<?php
}
?>
```