# Working with PHP and MySQL - need a good and secure OO design

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I am new to PHP-> first time developer. I am working on my web application and it is nearly done; nevertheless, most of my sql was done directly via code using direct mysql requests. This is the way I approached it:

In **classes_db.php** I declared the db settings and created methods that I use to open and close DB connections. I declare those objects on my regular pages:

```
class classes_db {

    public $dbserver = 'server;
    public $dbusername = 'user';
    public $dbpassword = 'pass';
    public $dbname = 'db';

    function openDb() {
        $dbhandle = mysql_connect($this->dbserver, $this->dbusername, $this->dbpassword);
        if (!$dbhandle) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        $selected = mysql_select_db($this->dbname, $dbhandle)
                or die("Could not select the database");

        return $dbhandle;
    }


    function closeDb($con) {
        mysql_close($con);
    }
}
```

On my regular page, I do this:

```
<?php
require 'classes_db.php';
session_start();

//create instance of the DB class
$db = new classes_db();

//get dbhandle
$dbhandle = $db->openDb();

//process query
$result = mysql_query("update user set username = '" . $usernameFromForm . "' where iduser= " . $_SESSION['user']->iduser);

//close the connection
if (isset($dbhandle)) {
    $db->closeDb($dbhandle);
}

?>
```

My questions is: how to do it right and make it OO and secure? I know that I need incorporate prepared queries-> how to do it the best way? Please provide some code

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` and use PDO with prepared queries.  As it stands right now, you are likely wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I know that, this is the purpose of my question-> please provide some best way to improve it. Thank you

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: See http://bobby-tables.com/php.html for examples of how to properly use parametrized SQL queries.

Comment: @Andrew, I did suggest a way to fix it... Use PDO with prepared queries.

Comment: OP, see my answer. It will help keep things secure, and DRY http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stop using mysql_* , use mysqli and **PDO** instead

[PHP PDO vs normal mysql_connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402017/php-pdo-vs-normal-mysql-connect)

> mysql_* functions are getting old. For a long time now mysql_* has
> been at odds with other common SQL database programming interfaces. It
> doesn't support modern SQL database concepts such as prepared
> statements, stored procs, transactions etc... It's method for escaping
> parameters with mysql_real_escape_string and concatenating into SQL
> strings is error prone and old fashioned. The other issue with mysql_*
> is that it has had a lack of attention lately from developers, it is
> not being maintained... Which could mean things like security
> vulnerabilities are not getting fixed, or it may stop working
> altogether with newer versions of MySQL. Also lately PHP community
> have seen fit to start a soft deprecation of mysql_* which means you
> will start seeing a slow process of eventually removing mysql_*
> functions altogether from the language (Don't worry this will probably
> be awhile before it actually happens!).
>
> PDO has a much nicer interface, you will end up being more productive,
> and write safer and cleaner code. PDO also has different drivers for
> different SQL database vendors which will allow you to easily use
> other vendors without having to relearn a different interface. (though
> you will have to learn slightly different SQL probably). Instead of
> concatenating escaped strings into SQL, in PDO you bind parameters
> which is an easier and cleaner way of securing queries. Binding
> parameters also allow for a performance increase when calling the same
> SQL query many times with slightly different parameters. PDO also has
> multiple methods of error handling. The biggest issue I have seen with
> mysql_* code is that it lacks consistent handling, or no handling at
> all! With PDO in exception mode, you can get consistent error handling
> which will end up saving you loads of time tracking down issues.
>
> PDO is enabled by default in PHP installations now, however you need
> two extensions to be able to use PDO: PDO, and a driver for the
> database you want to use like pdo_mysql. installing the MySQL driver
> is as simple as installing the php-mysql package in most
> distributions.

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend RedBeanPHP. It's a very solid MySQL database library that abstracts out all of the connection, querying, sanitization, preparation, uses PDO, etc. of your database interaction (which would be great for you, considering you are new to PHP development).

Check it out here: http://redbeanphp.com/

An example of how easy it is to set up a connection:

```
require('rb.php');
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mydatabase','user','password');
```

Setting up RedBeanPHP: http://redbeanphp.com/manual/setup

When creating a class to deal with your database objects, you'll want to use an interface and/or an abstract class to set certain object behavior rules (think CRUD...).

All you need to do is include that database connection in a common file, include it in all of your PHP scripts, and you're all set.

Comment: I disagree that using a library like this is good for new developers. They need know how PHP and MySQL work before trying libraries so they know how to fix problems with the library when they arise.

Comment: Totally disagree. Newcomers should start with tools that ensure proper patterns and practices, and discover the finer points of a language/stack further down the line. The last thing you want to do as a new developer is jump into the deep end without knowing how to swim.