# LIMIT style functionality in MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I've seen quite a few really horrid ways to do something like MySQL's LIMIT function for MS SQL.

Can anyone suggest a nice elegant way to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM blah LIMIT 5,15;
```

but in MS SQL?

Cheers!

Comment: It's interesting how the search for related questions works in different situations on SO. Currently the *Related* list contains the links to some questions that might very well eliminate the need for this one, namely these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server. Yet when I clicked *Ask Question* and entered this question's title, the list of related questions wasn't the same, and it certainly didn't have anything as relevant as the questions mentioned.

Comment: Yes, I always take care to have a look through the list - stack overflow fail perhaps? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server's equivalent to MySQL/PostgreSQL's LIMIT syntax is TOP (SQL Server 2000+), but [TOP doesn't support the offset value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)...

Assuming SQL Server 2005+, use:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ?) AS rank
          FROM BLAH t) x
 WHERE x.rank BETWEEN 6 AND 20
```

Mind that you have to define a sort order for the ranking - replace the "?" with the appropriate column(s).

Comment: I gave you the tick - your answer is pretty much the same as Sachin Shanbhag's, but you were a bit quicker :p

Comment: @John Hunt: Actually, Sachin was first but I stand by my comment that the Sachin's limit implementation isn't exactly what MySQL's LIMIT would produce given equivalent data.

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to obtain the same in SQL Server for `LIMIT 5,15` would be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` -

```
With t As
(
    Select ...
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( Order By ... ) As Num
    From Table
)
Select ...
From t
Where Num Between 5 And 15
```

Comment: That's not the correct equivalent [end value based on the offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Comment: Both pretty good answers from Sachin Shanbhag and OMG Ponies, shame Microsoft wouldn't just implement LIMIT...oh well. Thanks!

Comment: @John Hunt: Luckily syntax has been ANSI'd, but it's `FETCH FIRST x ROWS` -- DB2 is the only one that currently supports it (to my knowledge).