# Need a SQL select statement for pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a MySQL table with columns id, name and active.  I need to write a SQL select statement that will return a subset of the id's from this table starting at a specific row number, returning the next 20 rows inclusive.  For example:

```
id   name   active
------------------
a    One    true
b    Two    true
c    Three  true
d    Four   false
e    Five   true
f    Six    false
```

I need to be able to say start at row 3 in the table and return the id's for the next 3 rows inclusive (c, d and e).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  MyTable
Limit 2,3
```

Comment: Great, I actually just found this online (http://www.phpsimplicity.com/tips.php?id=1).  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the syntax is:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT <start>, <length>
```

So in your case:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 2, 3
```

Comment: I've not seen that syntax before, is it specific to MySQL or will it work in MS Sql Server?

Comment: I [don't believe MS SQL has `LIMIT`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server), I think it has `TOP` instead.