# How to convert mysql query into SQL Server query?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How to covert mysql query into mssql query?

```
SELECT name FROM user LIMIT 5, 10
```

I have known that mssql don't support 'limit'...

But I have to use `limit`!

How to covert mysql query into SQL Server query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: You need to specify an order criteria. There is a primary key/unique index/unique constraint on this table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
(select name , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by name) rn from user ) a
where rn > 5 and rn<= 15
```

Answer (score 2):

Try out this

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) as row FROM sys.databases 
 ) a WHERE a.row > 5 and a.row <= 10
```

You can achieve your concept.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to translate this, but there is a bit of workaround here on SO. 
[Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server)