# SQL LIMIT 1 DESC order

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to show only the highest selling product per work center, however, it keeps telling me that LIMIT 1 is the incorrect syntax. I cant seem to find an answer on here that has helped so I decided to ask the question. Here's my query.

```
SELECT WorkCenter.WorkCenterCode, Product.Name, SUM(CustomerOrderLine.Quantity*CustomerOrderLine.ActualPrice) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM WorkCenter 
    INNER JOIN Product ON WorkCenter.WorkCenterCode = Product.WorkCenterCode 
    INNER JOIN CustomerOrderLine ON Product.ProductID = CustomerOrderLine.ProductID
    GROUP BY WorkCenter.WorkCenterCode, Product.Name
    ORDER BY 'Total Sales' DESC 
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please add the appropriate tag to your question.

Comment: SQL Server Management studio and Visual Studio to create the reports

Comment: What's the *exact* error you get?

Comment: Incorrect Syntax near 'LIMIT'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your query cleaned up a bit:

```
SELECT  wc.WorkCenterCode, p.Name, SUM(col.Quantity*col.ActualPrice) AS "Total Sales"
FROM WorkCenter wc INNER JOIN
     Product p
     ON wc.WorkCenterCode = p.WorkCenterCode INNER JOIN
     CustomerOrderLine col
     ON p.ProductID = col.ProductID
GROUP BY wc.WorkCenterCode, p.Name
ORDER BY "Total Sales" DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note the important change from double quotes to single quotes.  This is especially important for the `order by` clause so the clause actually does something, rather than sorting by a constant.  The addition of table aliases makes the query easier to read.

If you are using Visual Studio, you should use `top` rather than `limit`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 wc.WorkCenterCode, p.Name, SUM(col.Quantity*col.ActualPrice) AS "Total Sales"
FROM WorkCenter wc INNER JOIN
     Product p
     ON wc.WorkCenterCode = p.WorkCenterCode INNER JOIN
     CustomerOrderLine col
     ON p.ProductID = col.ProductID
GROUP BY wc.WorkCenterCode, p.Name
ORDER BY "Total Sales" DESC;
```

EDIT:

For one row per work center, use this as a subquery with `row_number()`:

```
SELECT WorkCenterCode, Name, "Total Sales"
FROM (SELECT wc.WorkCenterCode, p.Name, SUM(col.Quantity*col.ActualPrice) AS "Total Sales",
             row_number() over (partition by wc.WorkCenterCode order by SUM(col.Quantity*col.ActualPrice) desc) as seqnum
      FROM WorkCenter wc INNER JOIN
           Product p
           ON wc.WorkCenterCode = p.WorkCenterCode INNER JOIN
           CustomerOrderLine col
           ON p.ProductID = col.ProductID
      GROUP BY wc.WorkCenterCode, p.Name
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY "Total Sales" DESC;
```

Comment: That worked, I kept switching back and forth between Visual Studio and SQL Server and it messed me up. That shows the top Work Center, I thought the way I had written it, that it would show the top selling for all work centers.

Comment: Im sure it is a simple fix, but how do I filter it to just one row per work center in order to show just the top highest selling product per work center.

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER()` - see below.

Comment: @Gordon, I am genuinely intrigued.  I've just looked through the whole [TSQL spec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) for `SELECT` and can't find the `LIMIT` clause anywhere.  What version of SQL Server are you running against?  I want to learn about this, please.

Comment: @MichaelGreen . . . I don't understand your question.  The point of my answer is that SQL Server uses `TOP` and not `LIMIT` (although the most recent version does now support `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`).

Comment: @Gordon - so the first block of code in your answer is not a proposed solution, just a re-statement of his question, refactored for clarity.  Fair enough; I understand now.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: @MichaelGreen . . . Yes.  The query actually had another fatal problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server use `SELECT TOP 1`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WorkCenter.WorkCenterCode, Product.Name, SUM(CustomerOrderLine.Quantity*CustomerOrderLine.ActualPrice) AS [Total Sales]
FROM            WorkCenter INNER JOIN
                     Product ON WorkCenter.WorkCenterCode = Product.WorkCenterCode INNER     JOIN
                     CustomerOrderLine ON Product.ProductID = CustomerOrderLine.ProductID
GROUP BY WorkCenter.WorkCenterCode, Product.Name
ORDER BY [Total Sales] DESC
```

Comment: Why? What did you change? Code-only answers are not as useful without an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server) on the topic which uses `ROW_NUMBER()`.  `TOP 1` will only return one row in total whereas `ROW_NUMER()` can return one row per group.