# In ColdFusion how to Convert LIMIT function query in MY SQL to MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: mysql, sql-server, coldfusion, sql-server-2012, mssql-jdbc

Please see below example:

```
<cfquery name="getAllMembers" datasource="#application.dsn#">
    SELECT  DCNumber,RegDate,gender,FirstName,LastName,(select count(*) from DriversRecord) as totalCount
            FROM DriversRecord

    LIMIT <cfqueryparam value="#start#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />,<cfqueryparam value="#paginationArgs.rowsPerPage#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />
</cfquery>
```

How can I covert  this query  which is in MY SQL But I am using MS SQL 2012 MS SQL?

Comment: Going with what I know, which is not very much, I'd look at sql server's rank function.

Comment: This isn't a ColdFusion question, is it? Isn't it just T-SQL?

Comment: Thank you Adam, I did go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server , before I post this Question, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Thank you Adam and Dan, I did go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server , before I post this Question, but it didn't work for me. I am sorry I am new to ColdFusion,how can i make this query to work in MS SQL

Comment: I did try this but now luck  <cfquery name="getAllMembers" datasource="#application.dsn#">
 SELECT  DCNumber,RegDate,gender,FirstName,LastName,(select count(*) from DriversRecord) as totalCount
   FROM DriversRecord
 where totalCount between <cfqueryparam value="#start#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" /> AND <cfqueryparam value="#paginationArgs.rowsPerPage#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" />

Comment: Previous to SQL Server 2012, I'd say the linked answer would be appropriate, but with 2012, there is now OFFSET-FETCH available which makes pagination almost as easy. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx **SELECT First Name + ' ' + Last Name FROM Employees ORDER BY First Name OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;**

Comment: If you are able to edit closed questions, please edit this one to show your attempt to use the answer from the other thread.  Also be more specific than "it didn't work for me".