# PHP SQL Server Alternative for TOP and LIMIT of MYSQL

Tags: php, sql, limit

I'm trying to figure out on how can i translate the codes I've created in php mysql to php sqlsrv.

Basically, I used LIMIT in MySQL to limit the pagination. However, this is not supported in SQL Server and I'm really having a hard time like 3 months already to figure this out.

Below is the MySQL Code I wanted to translate on SQLSRV:

```
$start="";
$per_page = 1;
$start = $_GET['start'];
$max_pages = ($foundnum / $per_page);
if(!$start)
$start=0; 
$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM knowledgebase WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");
```

And below code is what I currently have issues running in SQLSRV:

```
$start="";
$per_page = 1;
$start = $_GET['start'];
$max_pages = ($foundnum / $per_page);
if(!$start)
$start=0; 
$construct1 ="SELECT * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct";
$run1=sqlsrv_query($con,$construct1, array(), array('scrollable' => 'keyset'));
```

I can easily add LIMIT in the line of code $construct1 ="SELECT * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct"; but I didn't do it as it is not possible anyway.

Anyone can kindly help me out on how I can possible translate or rewrite it?
TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these posts. Simulating LIMIT from MySQL is little bit tricky.

[LIMIT 10..20 in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server)

[How to implement LIMIT with Microsoft SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server)

**From SQL server 2012** there is [OFFSET and FETCH](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx).

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY FirstName OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

It should be equivalent to LIMIT 10, 5.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But there seems to be a problem when i try to apply the variable for paginating a web page, just like what I did in mysql. I dont have any idea on how can I achieve the same goal I used: $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM knowledgebase WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");. I applied it in the information you have given melike this: $construct1 ="SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as row FROM ENSEMBLE 
 ) a WHERE row > $start and row <= 10" ;

Comment: Well if I understand your code well it looks like `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) as row FROM ENSEMBLE ) a WHERE row > $start AND row <= $start + $per_page`. Rows are numbered from 1 to n. Instead LIMIT 10, 5 (for example), you need rows from number 11 to number 15. Remember, unlike mysql, rows are numbered from 1 instead 0 like with LIMIT.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me resolved it, + reminding me that rows in sqlsrv starts with 1. Appreciate it alot.

Comment: I am glad to help you. You can accept my answer as solution of you problem.

Answer (score 1):

TOP is the equivalent of LIMIT in sql server: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

As has been pointed out below, TOP is not the equivalent realy. In fact you need to use OFFSET and FETCH to exactly match the LIMIT behaviour:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx

Comment: If you want to ask for further help, do not edit my answer but add a coment below it, or ask another question. In this case, ask another question as that is another problem.

Comment: TOP is not equivalent to MySQL limit because it does not support offset. You can not easily make a pagination with only TOP clause.