# PHP SQLSRV TOP Functionality, not the same with MySQL LIMIT

Tags: php, sql-server, limit

This is a follow-up question from previous post: [PHP SQL Server Alternative for TOP and LIMIT of MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29064262/php-sql-server-alternative-for-top-and-limit-of-mysql/29064310#29064310)

TOP is the equivalent of LIMIT in sql server: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

It does work somehow when I type in:

```
 $construct1 ="SELECT TOP $per_page * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct";
```

but when I add $start:

```
 $construct1 ="SELECT TOP $start, $per_page * FROM ENSEMBLE WHERE $construct";
```

It gives me an error message saying..

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\trueensemble\search1.php on line 51

I decided running error reporting after that to get a detailed error and I got:

> [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. )

I tried removing comma, now gives me an error message:

> [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'. )

I saw this post: [Equivalent of LIMIT and OFFSET for SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135418/equivalent-of-limit-and-offset-for-sql-server),  but I have no idea how can I rewrite it using the code I used in mysql..

Comment: remove `TOP` and add `limit 1,1` to the end

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2012+, you can use `FETCH`/`OFFSET`.