# How to select all records from a table except for the first 5 records?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to querying a tables in mysql and also using a stored procedure. I have this query below I want to query all data that is `>5`. Is there a query something like this `select * from table Except top 5` so it will start from data `#6` I search some code but I only find is a direct query w/o a condition.

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.PersonSkill INNER JOIN
    dbo.SpecialSkill ON dbo.PersonSkill.SpecialSkillsId = dbo.SpecialSkill.SpecialSkillsId
WHERE dbo.PersonSkill.PersonId = @PersonId
```

Comment: And this is about MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server doesnt have LIMIT or OFFSET Function but you can simulate this behaviour like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server) , and the result is like :

```
;WITH Results_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        dbo.PersonSkill.*, dbo.SpecialSkill.SpecialSkillsId, dbo.SpecialSkill.OtherCol
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @PersonId) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM dbo.PersonSkill 
    INNER JOIN dbo.SpecialSkill 
    ON dbo.PersonSkill.SpecialSkillsId = dbo.SpecialSkill.SpecialSkillsId
    WHERE dbo.PersonSkill.PersonId = @PersonId 
)
SELECT *
FROM Results_CTE
WHERE RowNum >5
```

Comment: What does Results_CTE means?.

Comment: Alias for temporary table

Comment: i got this error `The column 'SpecialSkillsId' was specified multiple times for 'Results_CTE'.
`

Comment: replace `select *` by specifics collumn like `select dbo.PersonSkill.*,dbo.SpecialSkill.SpecialSkillsId, dbo.SpecialSkill.OtherCol,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @PersonId) AS 'RowNum' ..... `

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use LIMIT parameter.

```
LIMIT 5, 10
```

First parameter (5) - start from

Second parameter (10) - how many rows to select

Comment: how can I use that in my query? sorry new here. I want to select all the rest of the data.

Comment: Read this documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html this site is not "I will write your code for free" Learn how it works. That is only one way how to make it and learn it.

Comment: `LIMIT` only makes good sense when used along with `ORDER BY`.  So you should add an ordering to the query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT     *
    FROM         dbo.PersonSkill INNER JOIN
                          dbo.SpecialSkill ON dbo.PersonSkill.SpecialSkillsId = dbo.SpecialSkill.SpecialSkillsId
    WHERE     dbo.PersonSkill.PersonId = @PersonId   and unique_id not in (SELECT   top 5  unique_id
    FROM         dbo.PersonSkill INNER JOIN
                          dbo.SpecialSkill ON dbo.PersonSkill.SpecialSkillsId = dbo.SpecialSkill.SpecialSkillsId
    WHERE     dbo.PersonSkill.PersonId = @PersonId )
```

Comment: the keyword LIMIT is in incorrect syntax. I am using sql server 2008 r2

Comment: Really, then you should amend your tag as strawberry suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @PersonId) as rn
FROM dbo.PersonSkill INNER JOIN
dbo.SpecialSkill ON dbo.PersonSkill.SpecialSkillsId = dbo.SpecialSkill.SpecialSkillsId
WHERE dbo.PersonSkill.PersonId = @PersonId)A where A.rn>5
```