# PHP Pagination MSSQL alternative to LIMIT?

Tags: php, sql-server, pagination, limit

To paginate a select query normally I would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE condition = 1 LIMIT $start, $items
```

However, in MSSQL there is no LIMIT condition, so I tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE condition = 1 OFFSET $start ROWS FETCH NEXT $items ROWS ONLY
```

And I get the error:

42000 - [SQL Server]Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

So what exactly should I do to paginate results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement LIMIT with Microsoft SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score 4):

This may help you.
The `OFFSET-FETCH` clause provides you with an option to fetch only a window or page of results from the result set. `OFFSET-FETCH` can be used only with the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT P_Name FROM ITEMS ORDER BY  P_Name OFFSET 10 ROWS;
```

SRC: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx

Comment: Nevermind, it executes the query now, but the pagination does not work. It selects always the same fields, even if $start is different...

Answer (score 0):

The MS SQL equivalent to MySQL's LIMIT clause is TOP.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM items WHERE condition = 1;
```

Will return the top ten rows, the same way it is done with LIMIT here:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE condition = 1 stuff LIMIT 10;
```

For more details (since I don't know all the context of your code) you can take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql).

Comment: But TOP only takes 1 param. So how would I get rows from 10-20 (for example) using TOP?