# SQL QUERY "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I've tried modifying a SQL query from an application but cannot get it working

the error:

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression."

the original query:

```
SELECT fycode, fyname, class3, '', '', '', defje, zjm, '', ''
FROM zy_fy

UNION ALL
SELECT Ypcode, Ypname,
    (SELECT a.lbname FROM YK_yplb a where a.lbid = b.yplb)
, gg, sldw, '', '', '', '', ''
FROM YK_ypzd b

UNION ALL
SELECT FYID, NAME, DYKS+'-'+CLASS2, '', '次', '', FYMONEY, ZJM, ZJM1, '' 
FROM mz_fy
```

the modified query:

```
SELECT fycode, fyname, class3, '', '', '', defje, zjm, '', ''
FROM zy_fy

UNION ALL
SELECT Ypcode, Ypname, 
(select a.lbname from YK_yplb a  where a.lbid = b.yplb)
,gg,sldw, '', 
(select c.dj from YK_kc c  where c.Ypcode = b.Ypcode)
 ,'','',''
FROM YK_ypzd b

UNION ALL
SELECT FYID, NAME, DYKS+'-'+CLASS2, '', '次', '', FYMONEY, ZJM, ZJM1, ''
FROM mz_fy
```

I've just inserted a subquery in the 7th column of the 3rd select statement

Thank you!

Comment: the error message is quite clear, the subquery is returning more than 1 value...you can see why that isn't allowed

Comment: which dbms are you using

Comment: All it takes is one record where the subquery returns multiple values to get this error. If you want multiple values, use a JOIN instead of a subquery. If the multiple values are trivial or you only want one, then use an aggregate function like MAX() to force the subquery to only return one value.

Comment: notwithstanding the impenetrable formatting, this is useless without example input data

Comment: How did you check that the query only returns one record? `SELECT c.Ypcode FROM YK_ypzd b INNER JOIN YK_kc c ON b.Ypcode = c.Ypcode GROUP BY c.Ypcode HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` should give you the row you need to address. If not, try the first query - perhaps data was entered in `YK_yplb` while you weren't looking?

Comment: it's mssql 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `TOP 1` to limit the subquery to return only one row

```
SELECT fycode, fyname, class3, '', '', '', defje, zjm, '', ''
FROM zy_fy

UNION ALL
SELECT Ypcode, Ypname, 
(select TOP 1 a.lbname from YK_yplb a  where a.lbid = b.yplb)
,gg,sldw, '', 
(select TOP 1 c.dj from YK_kc c  where c.Ypcode = b.Ypcode)
 ,'','',''
FROM YK_ypzd b

UNION ALL
SELECT FYID, NAME, DYKS+'-'+CLASS2, '', '次', '', FYMONEY, ZJM, ZJM1, ''
FROM mz_fy
```

Comment: **What** one row? Not explicitly ordering means you get an arbitrary row back, which is almost certainly not what the OP really wants.

Comment: Maybe that's what he want ‍♂️

Comment: That might be what they *think* they want, but it's probably just hiding the real problem. Also, I have no idea what those emoji are for.

Comment: Thank you! I've figured it out after reading @Sumesh TG's answer! Thanks again

Comment: I know, but small steps generally moves you forward to find the solution, or understand the problem

Answer (score 3):

```
    select fycode,fyname,class3,'','','',defje,zjm,'',''  from zy_fy union all
select  Ypcode, Ypname,(select a.lbname from YK_yplb a  where a.lbid =
b.yplb limit 1),gg,sldw,'',(select c.dj from YK_kc c  where c.Ypcode =
b.Ypcode),'','',''  from YK_ypzd b  union all  select FYID,NAME,DYKS+'-
+CLASS2,'','次','',FYMONEY,ZJM,ZJM1,''  from mz_fy
```

Use limit

Comment: Sorry, but (select a.lbname from YK_yplb a  where a.lbid =
b.yplb) just work. It's (select c.dj from YK_kc c  where c.Ypcode =
b.Ypcode),which I modeled after the former.

Comment: (A) `limit` is not MSSQL syntax, which the OP has (albeit unhelpfully in the comments) stated they are using. (B) Not explicitly ordering with `top` means you get an arbitrary row back, which is almost certainly not what the OP really wants.

Comment: There should be similar feature like LIMIT in mySql refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server)

Answer (score -1):

please use TOP 1 to limit the subquery to return only one row

Comment: Add some example or code to show how to achieve what you are saying.