# SQL where clause "up to" match

Tags: sql-server

I have the following two columns in a table.

[image]

Now, based on the data (ids in second columns) sent in from the client, I want to return the id from the first column as the following:

Client sends in: 13, returns **24**, **25** and **26**

Client sends in: 1, returns **24** and **26**

Client sends in: 1 and 13, returns **24** and **26**

Client sends in: 1, 12 and 13, returns **26**

How can I construct a `SQL query` like this? I've tried with `in operator`, but it returns wrong result in the last case where client sent in 1, 12 and 13. It returns all of them but I want only 26 in this case.

```
SELECT firstId FROM MyTable WHERE secondId in(1,12,13)
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971964/limit-10-20-in-sql-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT firstId
FROM tab
WHERE secondId in (1,12,13)
GROUP BY firstId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT secondId) = 3; -- number of elements from WHERE
```

Another approach is  to use `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT firstId FROM tab WHERE secondId = 1
INTERSECT
SELECT firstId FROM tab WHERE secondId = 12
INTERSECT
SELECT firstId FROM tab WHERE secondId = 13;
```