# Get Newest Data From Database Table

Tags: php, sql-server

I just Want to Get Newest Record From a Database Table and i got this error when i used LIMIT how can i solve this?

> Connection established.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. ) )


$query = 'SELECT EventTime, EventHumidity, EventTemperature FROM TxnFMISHumidityTempEvent ORDER BY EventID DESC LIMIT 1';
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $query );
if( $stmt === false) 
{
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    $css_class=' class="row"';
    echo "<tr '.$css_class.'>";
    echo "<td>SNSRP001</td>";
    echo "<td>MIS</td>";                
    echo "<td>" .$Date = $row['EventTime']->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'). "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['EventHumidity'].  "</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['EventTemperature'].  "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
```

Comment: seems like you're using MS-SQL, which does not understand `LIMIT 1`. you have to use `SELECT TOP 1`instead with it.

Comment: Can You explain it more please.

Comment: no. but google can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/603724/how-to-implement-limit-with-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: GOT IT Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIMIT` is not supported in SQL Server, you can use `TOP 1` instead of `LIMIT` with `ORDER BY`.

Change your `@query` like following.

```
$query = 'SELECT TOP 1 EventTime, EventHumidity, EventTemperature FROM TxnFMISHumidityTempEvent ORDER BY EventID DESC';
```

Answer (score 0):

try select * to select all data.

```
SELECT * FROM TxnFMISHumidityTempEvent ORDER BY primaryKeyId DESC LIMIT 1;
```